# How to attach a view attachment display to an Openlayer Data Overlay display?

Tags: 7, ajax, views, javascript

[Drupal 7, Views 3, OpenLayers]

### **THE PROPOSED SCENARIO:**

I would like to attach a view attachment display before an OpenLayer Data Overlay display. The attachment display would contain some exposed filters and a table of content data.

Using [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) I could enable auto submit and hide the submit button on the filter form at the attachment display, so both the attachment content table and the OpenLayer Data Overlay displays would get updated via AJAX. This would create a better user experience.

### **THE ISSUE:**

Apparently I can attach view attachment displays to any view display but OpenLayer Data Overlay displays.

### **THE QUESTION:**

Is there any work around or module implementation that could make it possible to attach a view attachment display to an OpenLayer Data Overlay display?

Another way to go would be perhaps having a block for the content data table and its filters. In this case, how could I get the AJAX on the block view to trigger the OpenLayer Data Ovelay view, so both views get the filters applied at the same time?

Comment: I've opened a feature request for this at the OpenLayer project module issue queue.

http://drupal.org/node/1879230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed scenario works just fine if you attach the attachment display to the OpenLayers Map display instead of to the OpenLayer Data Overlay.